# Using jQuery to manipulate entire HTML DOM

Tags: javascript, html, css

Is this a good practice? I mean is it good if all of my codes(behavior,presentation,structure) are inside on my .js(for example, since I'm making a website) file? Why? Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: So this isn't really about jQuery.

Comment: im a beginner, i just want to know the opinion of others.

Comment: This just isn't the place to solicit opinion. General discussion forums will be more suitable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obviously it is not good practice, the recommended practice is to split all the code into its designated file. The simplest method is to use multiple script tags with src.

If you're really interested in dividing up your code efficiently, I would suggest learning BoostrapJS or AngularJS.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I really can't make up whats next for me after I get to used in jQuery.